# Vaadin: how to avoid cascade valuechange events between fields

Tags: events, recursion, field, vaadin, onchange

I have several fields in a screen, that are partially dependent each on other by validating rules.

If user changes one field then I can affect another fields using setValue(). But I am fighting with the problem, valueChange event is fired from setValue() just as from user activity.
My example: I have four fields "activity_status", "schedule_date", "start_date", "end_date". By editing any one field I want to affect another three fields (changing status, setting or shifting dates). How to avoid recursive calling valueChange method?

I can imagine a variable justProcessedField that can working as a lock, but has anybody a better hands-on solution?

Comment: It's also what we do. We have a "global" variable holding the flag "insideValuechangeEvent". In each event listener we first check if that flag is set. When set, then don't do anything, else set the flag and update the other fields and then clear the flag agin

Comment: OK, I did something similar yesterday. If you write it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually we do set a flag when we trigger the first valueChangeEvent() and then ignore all others, until the first trigger is finished processing.

The pseudocode looks like this:

```
private boolean _ignoreTriggers= false; // Set ignore triggers when we do manual setValue stuff

field1.addListener(new ValueChangeListener()  {
        @Override
        public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
            if (!_ignoreTriggers) {
                _ignoreTriggers= true;
                // Do the processing and setValues(...) in the other fields
                _ignoreTriggers= false;
            }
        }
    }
);
```

With different booleans you can also make groups of fields "sensisble/insensible" to changes in other fields.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the ValueChangeEvents you can create custom fields, which are extentions of the fields you want to modify. This custom fields should have a public method which calls the `setInternalValue` method.

Example for Checkbox-Field:

```
public class CheckBoxSilent extends CheckBox {

    /**
     * Set the new value without calling a {@link ValueChangeListener}
     * 
     * @param newValue the new value to be set.
     */
    public void setValueSecretly(boolean newValue) {
        setInternalValue(newValue);
        markAsDirty();
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand but it is very laborious to inherit all field types and then replace them in all java sources. For this solution we must wait until somebody comes upon to modify AbstractField.

Comment: Is there a Bug/Enhancementrequest open for this in the vaadin bugtracker?